# Wordpress Sign-ups Using GA Goal Tracking

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, goal-tracking

I'm trying to use GA Tracking to Track Wordpress Sign-ups on my site. I'm assuming I need to use Goal Tracking and NOT Event tracking for this. I tried setting up goal tracking but it's not working. I am not using any GA plugins like Yoast, etc.

I can't get this to work with Wordpress:

1. I set my Goal URL to: `/wp-login.php?checkemail=registered` (URL landing page for sign-ups)
2. Match Type: "Exact Match"
3. No Goal Funnel was set.

GA is not tracking any of my sign-ups. What I am doing wrong here? My site is [www.StreetofWalls.com](http://www.streetofwalls.com) if you would like to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script that loads google-analytics isn't on the login page, so you're not getting any of the `/wp-login.php?checkemail=registered` pageviews sent back to google.

Put this on your wp-login.php page

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.streetofwalls.com/wp-content/themes/sow3/js/google-analytics.js'></script>
```

Comment: Great- thanks for the help Tom. I will do this now. I have another question for you - how can I test the conversion rates of sign-ups based on where I put my Registration embed? i.e. what if I want to see where people are registering at, my homepage, the "Register" button, the Register Widget on my "Jobs" tab, etc. Is there a way to build something in GA so I can monitor the highest converting Registration pages? Can I do this through Events or Goals or Funnels? I'm basically clue-less on where to start.

Comment: Have a goal for the page like you setup.  The rest of your question can be answered by opening your "Standard Reporting" tab and then browsing around the Conversion -> Goals section

Answer (score 0):

While TomFuertes's answer will work, it is not good to modify core WordPress files like `wp-login.php`. Updates to WordPress will overwrite any changes that you make and avoiding WordPress updates is a very bad idea.

I recommend adding the code using the `login_head` hook in your `functions.php` file:

```
function add_ga_to_login_page(){
  echo '<script>';
  echo 'GA TRACKING CODE HERE';
  echo '</script>';
}

add_action('login_head', 'add_ga_to_login_page');
```